# All combinations of a list without doubles in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

Is there a simple way of getting all the combinations of a list without doubles. Without doubles I mean also no permutations of each other. So no `[a,b,c]` and `[c,a,b]` or `[c,b,a]`.

So for the input [a,b,c] the output would be:

```
[a]
[b]
[c]
[a,b]
[a,c]
[b,c]
[a,b,c]
```

I can only find solutions WITH the doubles (permutations)

Comment: Can you assume that you will not feed it a list `[a,b,a]`?

Comment: @GuyCoder: If I understood the question correctly, this is about *generating* combinations.

Comment: @GuyCoder: what I think is that he means he want all combinations without repetition in taking, like `[a,a,a]` not being enumerated.

Comment: You can also give an upvote in addition to an accept vote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution to this problem is rather simple: there is evidently only one combination out of the empty set: the empty set:

```
combs([],[]).
```

Furthermore for each element, you can decide whether you add it or not:

```
combs([H|T],[H|T2]) :-
    combs(T,T2).
combs([_|T],T2) :-
    combs(T,T2).
```

Since you pick (or drop) in the order of the list, this guarantees you that you later will not redecide to pick `a`. If you feed it `[a,b,c]`, it will never generate something like `[b,a,c]`, because once it has decided to pick/drop `a`, it cannot add `b` and re-decide on `a`.

Running this gives:

```
?- combs([a,b,c],L).
L = [a, b, c] ;
L = [a, b] ;
L = [a, c] ;
L = [a] ;
L = [b, c] ;
L = [b] ;
L = [c] ;
L = [].
```

In case you want to generate it the opposite way (have more of a test to first drop elements, instead of adding them, you can simply swap the recursive statements):

```
combs([],[]).

combs([_|T],T2) :-
    combs(T,T2).
combs([H|T],[H|T2]) :-
    combs(T,T2).
```

In that case the result will be:

```
?- combs([a,b,c],L).
L = [] ;
L = [c] ;
L = [b] ;
L = [b, c] ;
L = [a] ;
L = [a, c] ;
L = [a, b] ;
L = [a, b, c].
```

## EDIT

Given you want to exclude the empty list, either you can do it simply by adding another check in your call:

```
?- combs([a,b,c],L),L \= [].
```

You can define this in a function like:

```
combs_without_empty1(LA,LB) :-
    combs_without_empty1(LA,LB),
    LB \= [].
```

Or by rewriting the `comb/2` function. In that case you better use an *accumulator* that counts the current amount of selected elements:

```
combs_without_empty(L,C) :-
    combs_without_empty(L,0,C).
```

The `combs_without_empty/3` is a bit more complicated. In case the list contains only one element, one should check if `N` is greater than zero. If that is the case, we can choose whether to add the element or not. If `N` is zero, we have to include it. So:

```
combs_without_empty([A],_,[A]).
combs_without_empty([_],N,[]) :-
    N > 0.
```

We also have to implement a recursive part that will increment `N` given we select an element:

```
combs_without_empty([_|T],N,T2) :-
    combs_without_empty(T,N,T2).
combs_without_empty([H|T],N,[H|T2]) :-
    N1 is N+1,
    combs_without_empty(T,N1,T2).
```

Putting it all together gives:

```
combs_without_empty(L,C) :-
    combs_without_empty(L,0,C).

combs_without_empty([A],_,[A]).
combs_without_empty([_],N,[]) :-
    N > 0.

combs_without_empty([_|T],N,T2) :-
    combs_without_empty(T,N,T2).
combs_without_empty([H|T],N,[H|T2]) :-
    N1 is N+1,
    combs_without_empty(T,N1,T2).
```

Which produces:

```
?- combs_without_empty([a,b,c],L).
L = [c] ;
L = [b, c] ;
L = [b] ;
L = [a, c] ;
L = [a] ;
L = [a, b, c] ;
L = [a, b] ;
false.
```

Comment: If I read the OP's question directly, it looks like they're not wanting to include `[]` as a valid solution (?).

Comment: How would I exclude the empty list? This answer was what I was looking for! I also don't really understand when the function combs([_|T],T2) is getting triggered instead of the other.

Comment: @Enforcerke: in that case there are two options, either rewrite the predicate; or add a check at the end. I've briefly discussed both.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thank you it's clear now. So basically you know for each head of your recursion it's either going to be included or excluded?

Comment: @Enforcerke: well due to Prolog's automatic branching you *choose* whether to include it or not, but you later return to take the other option.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem what i do not understand is that both the versions of combs get triggered? I always tought lets say you call combs([a,b,c], X) that it would take the first one it matches even if there are multiple that match (like in this case)

Comment: @Enforcerke: first of all you cannot use both versions concurrently (without renaming one of them). I assume however you mean that you use one version. That is one of the fundamental aspects of Prolog: automatic backtracking: if there are multiple heads that match, all heads will eventually be enumerated through backtracking.

Comment: This answer starts out great, but the second part using `combs/3` complicates the matter too much. A simpler way (with a nicer enumeration ordering) would be to use what you even mention and just define `combs_without_empty_list(List, Combination) :- combs(List, Combination), Combination \= [].`. Rename both predicates to taste.

Comment: How can the rsults be concatenated in one list?

Comment: @yonutix: with `findall/3`: https://www.swi-prolog.org/search?for=findall%2F3

Answer (score 4):

A clean solution without ancillary checks for empty list would be simply to exclude empty lists from the rules. The base case should be a single element combination:

```
comb_without_empty([H|_], [H]).   % Simple case of one element comb
comb_without_empty([_|T], C) :-   % Combinations of the tail w/o head
    comb_without_empty(T, C).
comb_without_empty([H|T], [H|C]) :-  % Combinations of the tail including head
    comb_without_empty(T, C).

| ?- comb_without_empty([a,b,c], L).

L = [a] ? a

L = [b]

L = [c]

L = [b,c]

L = [a,b]

L = [a,c]

L = [a,b,c]

(1 ms) no
| ?-
```